# What is the oracle 11i API for terminating the service contract line

Tags: oracle, api

I want to terminate the service contract line using oracle 11i API. What is the appropriate API for termination?

Comment: Refer to this [link](http://www.oracleappshub.com/api/apis-availability-in-oracle-service-contractsoks/)

Comment: You are Welcome